# Lambda expressions to JSON array

Tags: arrays, json, lambda

```
List<string> _columns = new List<string>() { "Kurator", "Filial", "Klient", "Saldo", "Docs", "no_Docs", "Change", "Status" };
var columns = cols.Select(p => new {
                    data = p.ColumnName   });
```

Tis gives me an array of objects JsonResult: data:Kurator, data:Filial etc.

Here is data = constant. How i can use it dynamically from another List???

So i need data from two list of objects

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>() { "lst1-1", "lst1-2", "lst1-3" };
List<string> list2 = new List<string>() { "lst2-1", "lst2-2", "lst2-3" };

var columns = cols.Select(p => new {
                        lst1-1= lst2-1   });
```

To get in return `Json(columns, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

> columns = array of (lst1-1:lst2-1,lst1-2:lst2-1, lst1-3:lst2-1)

i`m already break my head!!!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var columns = from l1 in list1.Select((val, index) => new { val, index })
                    from l2 in list2.Select((val, index) => new { val, index })
                    where l1.index == l2.index
                    select l1.val + " : " + l2.val;
```

Comment: it returns "lst1: lst2" as string but working input looks like { data = "Kurator" } its array of objects